# What is the best way to export a default value with typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I want to export a default value that can work with commonjs and es module.

- use 'export default'

```
export default a;

// with commonjs import, must add .default
const a = require('a').default
```

- use 'export ='

```
export = a;

// with es import, tsconfig moudle option should be commonjs
import a = require('a')
```

- expected

```
import a from 'a';
const a = require('a');
```

Are there any way to make it possible to using with both with commonjs and es module without extra handle?(I only have one value to export.)